# Check continuity and find norms of linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

1) $\ell^1\ni(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}\rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2013x_{2n}-2012x_{2n+1})\in \mathbb{R}$

2) $C[0,1]\ni f \rightarrow (a_n f(a_n))_{n=0}^{\infty} \in \ell^\infty$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{n+2012}$

**My attempt:**

1) $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|2013x_{2n}-2012x_{2n+1}| \le 2013\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_{2n}|+2012 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_{2n+1}| \le 2013 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_n|$$
Now take the sequence $(a_n)=(1,0,0,0 \dots)$ and we have equality, so the norm is equal to 2013.

2) $$\sup_n |\frac{f(a_n)}{n+2012}|\le \sup_n | \frac{\sup_t f(t)}{n+2012}|\le \frac{1}{2012} \sup_t |f(t)|$$

And the norm is equal to $1/2012$ since if we take $f=2012$ we have equality.

Good?

Comment: Yup. Both good.

Comment: The sequence $(a_n)$ for (1) is not in $l^1$! Take $(x_n)=(0,1,0,\dots)$.

Comment: good point, thanks